# Excluding folder and files from search

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I surrender, I spend my time almost 12hours to get what I want, but I can't.

This code search all folders and filenames, but I want to exclude some folders including the sub directory of folders I want to exclude from searching.

I wish there's someone can help.

```
procedure TForm1.CombineDir(InDir : string; OutStream : TStream);
var  AE : TArchiveEntry;
     dFound:boolean;

  procedure RecurseDirectory(ADir : string);
  var  sr : TSearchRec;
       TmpStream : TStream;
  begin
    if FindFirst(ADir + '*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then begin
      repeat
        if (sr.Attr and (faDirectory or faVolumeID)) = 0 then begin
          //ShowMessage('Filename is :>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
          if (NotThisPath.IndexOf(ADir + sr.Name)>=0) or dFound then begin
            ShowMessage('DO NOT INCLUDE THIS FILENAME :>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
          end else begin
            ShowMessage('>>> INCLUDE THIS FILENAME :>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
            // We have a file (as opposed to a directory or anything
            // else). Write the file entry header.
            AE.EntryType := aeFile;
            AE.FileNameLen := Length(sr.Name);
            AE.FileLength := sr.Size;
            OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
            OutStream.Write(sr.Name[1], Length(sr.Name));
            // Write the file itself
            TmpStream := TFileStream.Create(ADir + sr.Name, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
            OutStream.CopyFrom(TmpStream, TmpStream.Size);
            TmpStream.Free;
          end;
        end;

        if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) > 0 then begin
          if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then begin
            //ShowMessage('DIR is:>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
            //if (Pos(ADir, NotThisPath.Text)>0) then
            if (NotThisPath.IndexOf(ADir + sr.Name)>=0) then begin
              ShowMessage('DO NOT INCLUDE THIS DIR:>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
              dFound:=True;
            end else begin
              ShowMessage('>>> INCLUDE THIS DIR:>'+ ADir + sr.Name);
              // Write the directory entry
              AE.EntryType := aeDirectory;
              AE.DirNameLen := Length(sr.Name);
              OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
              OutStream.Write(sr.Name[1], Length(sr.Name));
            end;
            // Recurse into this directory
            RecurseDirectory(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ADir + sr.Name));
          end;
        end;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
    // Show that we are done with this directory
    AE.EntryType := aeEOD;
    OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
  end;

begin
RecurseDirectory(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(InDir));
end;
```

NotThisPath is a TStringList;

Comment: You should always take care to format your code sensibly - if it is not formatted well then nobody is going to read it.

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Delphi 7, not Delphi XEs

Comment: It looks like the format is good, how to, but the code was place in the code place.

Comment: But what is the problem? You have presented code, but no facts at all. What do you expect to happen? What did happen? More generally, you are making life hard for yourself by mixing everything into a single function. What you need to do is write a general purpose function that enumerates files. You can then choose to do whatever your like with the enumerated files.

Comment: You've said what you want to do. In what way does this code *not* do what you want? You need to be able to express your problem. Otherwise, you're at the mercy of other people being able to *guess* what you want, and when they guess wrong, you're going to be frustrated, and you'll still have the same problem you had before. I wonder why you recurse into a directory even after you determine that you're not supposed to include it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your fundamental problem is that you have mixed together file enumeration, file name filtering, and your GUI into one unholy blob of goo. You simply should not see `FindFirst` being called from a method of a form. Code that calls `FindFirst` belongs in helper classes or functions.

I'm not going to attempt to answer your question directly, not least because you did not actually ask a question. What I'm going to attempt is to show you how to separate the concerns of enumerating files and filtering for names.

First of all, I'm going to implement this function:

```
procedure EnumerateFiles(Dir: string; 
  const EnumerateFileName: TEnumerateFileNameMethod);
```

This function is passed a directory in the `Dir` parameter and it proceeds to enumerate all files within that directory, its sub-directories, and so on recursively. Each file that is found is passed to the callback method `EnumerateFileName`. This is defined like so:

```
type
  TEnumerateFileNameMethod = procedure(const FileName: string) of object;
```

The implementation is very simple indeed. It's just the standard `FindFirst` based repeat loop. The function rejects the special directories `.` and `..`. It will recurse into any directories that it encounters.

```
procedure EnumerateFiles(Dir: string;
  const EnumerateFileName: TEnumerateFileNameMethod);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  Dir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Dir);
  if FindFirst(Dir + '*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if (SR.Name = '.') or (SR.Name = '..') then
          continue;
        if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
          EnumerateFiles(Dir + SR.Name, EnumerateFileName)
        else
          EnumerateFileName(Dir + SR.Name);
      until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(SR);
    end;
end;
```

Now, this should be simple enough to follow I hope. The next issue is filtering. You can implement that in the callback method that you provide. Here's a complete demo that illustrates filtering that picks out Delphi source files with the `.pas` extension.

```
program EnumerateFilesDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TEnumerateFileNameMethod = procedure(const FileName: string) of object;

procedure EnumerateFiles(Dir: string;
  const EnumerateFileName: TEnumerateFileNameMethod);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  Dir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Dir);
  if FindFirst(Dir + '*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if (SR.Name = '.') or (SR.Name = '..') then
          continue;
        if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
          EnumerateFiles(Dir + SR.Name, EnumerateFileName)
        else
          EnumerateFileName(Dir + SR.Name);
      until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(SR);
    end;
end;

type
  TDummyClass = class
    class procedure EnumerateFileName(const FileName: string);
  end;

class procedure TDummyClass.EnumerateFileName(const FileName: string);
begin
  if SameText(ExtractFileExt(FileName), '.pas') then
    Writeln(FileName);
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  EnumerateFiles('C:\Users\heff\Development', TDummyClass.EnumerateFileName);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Now, I know that's not the type of filtering that you want to do, but the point is that we now have generality. You can replace the call to `SameText` with whatever filtering you want. And once you have picked out the files that you want to deal with, you can do what you like with them.

I used a class method for convenience. I did not want my demo to be laden down with the boiler-plate of instantiating an object. But for your needs you would want to create a class to handle the enumeration callback. That class would encapsulate the file archiving operation that you are performing. That class would own an instance of the output stream. And the callback method would be an instance method that would write to the archive.

Now, I've not implemented a complete solution to your problem, but I hope I've done something better. Namely to show you how to factor code to make solving your problem simple.